# Check list item in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have successfully put items into `ListView` using `BaseAdapter`, and what I want to ask is... is it possible to check whether `ListView` is empty in `onCreate()`, or get the total list count in `onCreate()`? Thanks.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Contact> list;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_contact,null);
        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_keranjang);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact);

        int contact_id = list.get(position).getId();
        String contact_name = list.get(position).getName();
        String contact_address = list.get(position).getAddress();

        id.setText(String.valueOf(contact_id));
        kode.setText(contact_name);
        judul.setText(contact_address);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String URL = "http://domain/contact.php";
        CustomAdapter customAdapter;
        int success = 0;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        ArrayList<Contact> listContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        JSONObject json=null;
        JSONArray contact=null;ListView li;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            new getContactAsync().execute();

            //int c = li.getAdapter().getCount(); not working

        }
    class getContactAsync extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList<Contact>>{


            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
                    json = jsonParser.getFromURL(URL);
                try {
                    contact = json.getJSONArray("contact");
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contact.getJSONObject(i);
                            Contact a = new Contact();
                            a.setId(c.optInt(TAG_ID));
                            a.setName(c.optString(TAG_NAME));
                            a.setAddress(c.optString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                            listContact.add(a);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                }
                return listContact;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,listContact);
                li.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String URL = "http://domain/contact.php";
        CustomAdapter customAdapter;
        int success = 0;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        ArrayList<Contact> listContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        JSONObject json=null;
        JSONArray contact=null;ListView li;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            new getContactAsync().execute();

            //int c = li.getAdapter().getCount(); not working

        }
    class getContactAsync extends AsyncTask<String,String,ArrayList<Contact>>{


            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
                    json = jsonParser.getFromURL(URL);
                try {
                    contact = json.getJSONArray("contact");
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contact.getJSONObject(i);
                            Contact a = new Contact();
                            a.setId(c.optInt(TAG_ID));
                            a.setName(c.optString(TAG_NAME));
                            a.setAddress(c.optString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                            listContact.add(a);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
                }
                return listContact;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if(listContact.size()>0)
            {
              customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,listContact);
              li.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
            else
            {
            //empty
            }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you have the `listContact`, do get the size of this since that is what you are passing to the adapter

```
listContact.size ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use your own BaseAdapter method `getCount()`

```
int number_of_element_in_listview = customAdapter.getCount();
```

But you should be doing it after initialising the variable `customAdapter` and also after assigning the values to it in the AsyncTask `getContactAsync` You have defined for it.

> is there possible to check listview is Empty in oncreate?

If the value `number_of_element_in_listview` is 0 then the listview will have no elements .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking it in `onCreate` you should check it in `onPostExecute` before creating adapter object.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if(listContact.size()>0){
       customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,listContact);
       li.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
}
```

This will create object of adapter only when your list is having item. If it is empty it will not create adapter object.

Now whenever you are referencing to adapter, you should check whether it is null or not before performing any operation later on.